# How can I get User Agent before any web request?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a WebExtension. I know that when a web request is made, I can get User Agent with [webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders). However, I would like to get User Agent before any web request is made, because I want to fetch a JSON file, during loading of my WebExtension, based on the User Agent. Is that possible?

Comment: are you fetching that JSON file from a server/backend?

Comment: Uhm, can you simply use `navigator.userAgent`?

Comment: @wOxxOm: OMG, I was so deep into WebExtensions API that I totally forgot about the normal client API. Of course I can use `navigator.userAgent`! Silly me!